# Dropdown menu dynamic to each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i just want to ask what went wrong with my codes? i have three dropdown selections, now what I want to happen is that if I select a name on selection 1, it will not show on selection 2 and selection 3. i want to it to be as flexible as it can be however i cant find a way to make it happen. badly need your help guys thank you guys

here's my code

this is my table

```
    ` <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>Gangway</th>
       <th>Time</th>
      <th>Name</th>
          
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>First Relieve</td>
          <td>0800H-1200H || 2000H-0000H</td>
          <td><div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          ';
              
                  // retrieve the list of names from the Personnel Status table
                  $names = array('Tony Parker', 'John Travolta', 'Bigboy Oneil');
                  echo '<option> </option>';
                  // generate the dropdown menu
                  foreach ($names as $name) {
                      
                      echo '<option href="#">' . $name . '</option>';
                  }
               echo '
          </select>
      </div></td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Second Relieve</td>
          <td>1200H-1600H || 0000H-0400H</td>
          <td><div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          ';
              
                  // retrieve the list of names from the Personnel Status table
                  $names = array('Tony Parker', 'John Travolta', 'Bigboy Oneil');
                  echo '<option> </option>';
                  // generate the dropdown menu
                  foreach ($names as $name) {
                      
                      echo '<option href="#">' . $name . '</option>';
                  }
               echo '
          </select>
      </div></td>
          
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Third Relieve</td>
          <td>1600H-2000H || 0400H-0800H</td>
          <td><div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
          ';
              
                  // retrieve the list of names from the Personnel Status table
                  $names = array('Tony Parker', 'John Travolta', 'Bigboy Oneil');
                  echo '<option> </option>';
                  // generate the dropdown menu
                  foreach ($names as $name) {
                      
                      echo '<option href="#">' . $name . '</option>';
                  }
               
          </select>
      </div></td>
          
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ';`
```

//and this is my javascript associated with it

`
// get all the dropdown menus
var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");

```
// add an event listener to each dropdown
selects.forEach(function(select) {
    
    select.addEventListener("change", function() {
        
        // get the selected option
        var selectedOption = this.value;
        
        // loop through all the dropdowns
        selects.forEach(function(otherSelect) {
            
            // skip the current dropdown
            if (otherSelect === select) {
                return;
            }
            
            // loop through all the options in the other dropdown
            var options = otherSelect.querySelectorAll("option");
            options.forEach(function(option) {
                
                // hide the selected option in the other dropdowns
                if (option.value === selectedOption) {
                    option.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    option.style.display = "";
                }
                
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`

Comment: [side note] One of the alternatives will be using a list (with checkbox for each item) allowing user to tick 3 checkboxes

Comment: but would it be the same ? if replace it by check boxes ?